# Server error on migrated away question

Tags: bug, status-completed, migrated-questions, ssl, 500-server-error

When I try to visit [this question on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292360/is-it-appropriate-to-reject-a-proposed-documentation-change-based-solely-on-its), I get a server error (HTTP 500).

It has been migrated away to meta.SO, where I can [look at it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345427/is-it-appropriate-to-reject-a-proposed-documentation-change-based-solely-on-its) without a problem.

It also works if I visit the [question with the `noredirect=1` parameter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292360/is-it-appropriate-to-reject-a-proposed-documentation-change-based-solely-on-its?noredirect=1). So I guess something with the redirection handling is messed up.

The [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/292360/revisions) and [the timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/292360/timeline) here on meta.SE don't show any error.

Comment: Yeah, the logic that looks up the destination URL assumes the destination URL starts with "http://"... HTTPS ruins everything.

Comment: https-bugs-everywhere?

Comment: You get an https bug, you get an https bug, every-body-gets-an-https-bug!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var result = record.Comment.Substring(record.Comment.IndexOf("http://"));`

This is why we can't have nice things.

A quick fix is out in prod now, but we (well, Nick Craver) will be looking at switching up how we track migrations to avoid this sort of direct string parsing.